# Hanging of C# WinForm Application when updating richtextbox with processing steps

Tags: c#

through every step of my very long-code scheduling processing, I write down the result to a richTextBox, with lines that might exceeds thousands of lines,  the application falls in the "not responding status", i discovered this problem by chance just when i disable this step. But, i still need a way to get a complete description of my app processing history, do you have any alternative suggestions

my code seems like that:

```
public void mycode()
{
//code part one
richTextBox1.text += "result is: abc";

//code part two
richTextBox1.text += "result is: efg";

//code part three
richTextBox1.text += "result is: hij";

}
```

Comment: question makes NO sense.

Comment: @MitchWheat, this is a real problem i face when i have hundreds of lines in richtextbox in millisecond processing

Comment: yes, and you've explained it so well....it's right up there with some of the worst asked questions I've had the misfortune to see in 5 years.

Comment: Not responding is something you get where your app is too busy to respond to windows messages. Of course taking many messages out of the queue improves things. Your logging mechanism is, how can put this awful. Write it to stringbuilder or a stream and then fill the textbox when it's finished. Every one of those concatenates, creates a new string.

Comment: thanks all colleagues for kind attention.... yes, my application is concerned with potential scheduling probabilities; So, it deals with hundreds of thousands of probabilities, that's why it causes my app not responding. i want to have a very detailed log file, without affecting my app., that's the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you move your long running task to a separate thread. Any other approach will give you pain in the long run. Trying to keep a GUI updated properly and responding to events while running a long task in the GUI thread itself is so error-prone that you're better off not going there.

Read this article here, it's quite clear as a starting point on multithreading in WinForms GUIs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171728(v=vs.100).aspx